# PHP 8.2 + Memcached как session handler не работает

Tags: php, memcached

Установил Memcached пеклом. Добавил extension в php.ini. Я вижу в выводе phpinfo() секцию Memcached, также сменил session.save_handler → Memcached и session.save_path → 127.0.0.1:11211

Теперь при вызове session_start() я пулочую:
session_start(): Failed to write session lock: SERVER HAS FAILED AND IS DISABLED UNTIL TIMED RETRY
session_start(): Unable to clear session lock record
session_start(): Failed to read session data: Memcached

В чем проблема с Memcached?
Я проверил отдельно его все сохраняется и все читается, но сессии не работают.

Comment: По-моему хранить сессии в memcached это плохая идея, так как memcached принципиально не предназначен для постоянного хранения данных и может потерять сессии при любом чихе

Comment: Почему нет? Нормальный сервер в нормальном ЦОДе при любом чихе не ребутится. Memcached теряет данные только от ребута. У меня аптайм уже больше 5 лет, обновил php и вот проблема. Хранить сессии в файлах медленно, когда их больше миллиона.

Comment: Во-первых, memcached теряет данные не только от ребута сервера, но и от ребута самого́ memcached и от переполнения памяти. Во-вторых, выбор не ограничивается только файлами и memcached, есть ещё например Redis, который работает в памяти очень быстро, но периодически (периодичность можно настроить) сохраняет данные на диск, что позволяет им успешно пережить ребут

Comment: Нехватки памяти не светит, редиска работает, но хочу разобраться что не так с Memcached. Потеря сессий это не критично для нашего сервиса.

Comment: @InDevX это только для Memcache tcp:// для Memcached только хост и порт

Comment: Memcached конфиг стандартный? Попробуйте память увеличить

Comment: да стандартный. Хорошо попробую

Comment: Вполне может быть вам придется писать свой [собственный обработчик](https://serverfault.com/questions/916129/php-7-2-failed-to-read-session-data-memcache), либо проверять настройки [lock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58875733/inconsistent-memcached-php-session-read-error-after-migrating-to-php-7), либо вообще отключать его.

Comment: `memcached.sess_locking=offf` в пхп.ини